# Running a Maven project - goal 'add-maven-repo'

Tags: java, maven

I just took over a Maven project, prior to that I do not have experience in working with Maven. What is the error below about? There is very little information on this 'add-maven-repo' online. How do I go about resolving it?

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'add-maven-repo' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:
maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10 among available goals clean, configure-workspace, ecli
pse, help, install-plugins, myeclipse, myeclipse-clean, rad, rad-clean, remove-c
ache, resolve-workspace-dependencies, to-maven -> [Help 1]
```

This is the command I ran

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace=<my_workspace_absolute_path> eclipse:add-maven-repo
```

Comment: Why are you using `maven-eclipse-plugin`? The entire plugin is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems `add-maven-repo` is deprecated. You can try with: `eclipse:configure-workspace`

http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-eclipse-plugin-2.8/add-maven-repo-mojo.html
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-configure-m2_repo-variable-in-eclipse-ide/

Comment: Well, the entire plugin is not supported anymore and officially retired. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: yes, you are right, is better to use m2e plugin but in disclaimer section says that still is useful in some situations